# Bank account question

Tags: bank-account

On Nov. 16th last month my buddy used my debit card to order something online for $245. He gave me $250 cash, I deposited it, and bought the item he wanted online. The money was taken out of my account that moment. A few days later he received the item but it was the wrong one. He called and they sent him the right one. 10 days ago I see the deposit of $250 on my mobile banking app. And I have $250 that should have already been spent. It's been 10 days and it's still there.

What happened? Did they possibly refund him and return the correct item? Dad says I'm dreaming if I think that happens. But anyway, what happened here? Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever see any transactions for $245 on your account? If refunded I'd expect two transactions. Mistakes certainly happen, and once in a while they benefit you.

Comment: Can you list all of the transactions related to this purchase that appear in your account and the dates they occurred? Perhaps even a screenshot of the relevant details (and non-relevant blanked out).

Comment: Yes thank you so much for the responses. The only transaction listen or visible is the cash deposit of $245 in the branch. Nothing else is shown anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

First, assume the money is "spoken for" until proven otherwise – in other words, don't spend it (again) until the matter is resolved.

Next, check with your friend as to the exact sequence of events: did he call, has he returned anything, has he received the correct item. Get copies of any paperwork that might have come with any of this.

Double-check you account transactions for $250/$245 items coming in and going out. It would seem unlikely, but it's plausible that the company refunded the $245 when notified of an incorrect delivery and are in the process of recharging for the correctly sent item.

If you still cannot make things "add up" properly, call the company and explain what happened and ask them what's going on. While it's possible that they've "forgotten" to (re)charge you for the item, and 'phoning them may remind them to do so, overall it's the safest thing to do... Assuming your friend now has the right item, you're morally/legally bound to pay for it, and if you assume they've forgotten, spend the money and *then* they apply the charge, you could go overdrawn or otherwise end up with problems.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I transferred the money to my father's account so that I would not be tempted haha. I will try your advice. Thanks again.